# Does Rust's standard library support direct IO file access?

Tags: io, rust, buffer

Is there a way to specify `O_DIRECT` with Rust's standard library, or do you need to use [libc](https://github.com/jsgf/libaio-rust/blob/master/src/directio.rs)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **Unix specific** extension trait [`os::unix::fs::OpenOptionsExt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/fs/trait.OpenOptionsExt.html):

```
use std::{fs::OpenOptions, os::unix::fs::OpenOptionsExt};

const O_DIRECT: i32 = 0o0040000; // Double check value

fn main() {
    OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .custom_flags(O_DIRECT)
        .open("/etc/passwd")
        .expect("Can't open");
}
```

The value of `O_DIRECT` is platform-specific, however. I'd probably end up using libc to provide the value.

Comment: I was able to get your example to run, but as soon as I add `.create(true)` I get `IO(Os { code: 22, kind: InvalidInput, message: "Invalid argument" })`.

Comment: @Fallen Not sure. [*`EINVAL` The filesystem does not support the `O_DIRECT` flag*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), plus a page or so of "read this about `O_DIRECT`"

Comment: I could not find a difinitive answer to whether ext4 or tmpfs (this one seems unlikely) support Direct IO but neither of them worked when I added the `.create(true)` flag. I ended up using a raw block device (`/dev/nvme0n1p3` - my nvme drive) and that worked since I don't need the create flag anymore.

Comment: On kernel 5.4.2 `O_DIRECT` did not work on `tmpfs` but worked on `btrfs`.

Comment: `EINVAL` on writes with direct I/O usually implies that any of the three -  write buffer source address, target offset in the file, write size - is misaligned. See the corresponding note on `EINVAL` in  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html

Comment: @FrankH, what you said is correct, when the alignment restriction is not satisfied, the syscall returns with `EINVAL` (though this is not true for btrfs, btrfs will fall back to buffered I/O when the restriction is not met). But the code in this answer does NOT perform any `read(2)/write(2)` operations, it just opens the file and gets the file descriptor. @Fallen, I can reproduce your error when `.create(true)` is added, and I am pretty sure btrfs (the fs I am using) supports direct I/O.

Comment: @Fallen, I get it, this `EINVAL` is returned by rust stdlib, not the OS. Rust has some restrictions on what can be set in an `OpenOption`, one of such restrictions is `To `truncate/create/create_new` a file, `write` must be set.`. If you are interested in these restrictions, you can check my [note: Checking of invalid OpenOptions value](https://github.com/SteveLauC/fs/blob/main/funny_stuff.md)